# How to handle ephemeral port exhaustion in envoy

Tags: kubernetes, port, reverse-proxy, envoyproxy

One of the problems with reverse proxies handling multiple requests on behalf of clients is, after a while under heavy load, the number of outgoing connections from envoy node to backend nodes will run out of ephemeral ports

Assuming that we have assigned multiple ip addreses/hostnames to envoy node, is there a way to inform envoy use these ip addresses/hostnames in a round robin fashion when making connections to backends?

References:

1. https://blog.box.com/blog/ephemeral-port-exhaustion-and-web-services-at-scale/
2. https://making.pusher.com/ephemeral-port-exhaustion-and-how-to-avoid-it/
3. https://www.nginx.com/blog/overcoming-ephemeral-port-exhaustion-nginx-plus/
4. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27398

Answer (score 3):

The most promising option is to find a way to enable TCP multiplexing between your proxy/LB and backend servers.

> ### [What is TCP Multiplexing?](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/3-really-good-reasons-you-should-use-tcp-multiplexing)
>
> TCP multiplexing is a technique used primarily by load balancers and application delivery controllers (but also by some stand-alone web application acceleration solutions) that enables the device to "reuse" existing TCP connections. This is similar to the way in which persistent HTTP 1.1 connections work in that a single HTTP connection can be used to retrieve multiple objects, thus reducing the impact of TCP overhead on application performance.
>
> TCP multiplexing allows the same thing to happen for TCP-based applications (usually HTTP / web) except that instead of the reuse being limited to only 1 client, the connections can be reused over many clients, resulting in much greater efficiency of web servers and faster performing applications.

Another good explanation about TCP multiplexing can be found [here](http://qnimate.com/what-is-multiplexing-in-http2/).

Another option is adding more proxy instances  to the pool behind the L4 network Load Balancer and set connection limit for one instance to reasonable value.
Each proxy would carry a certain amount of load without a problem. If you need to handle periodic bursts in load, you may want to set auto scaling strategy to the proxy pool.